# How many logstash workers shall I allocate for a kafka topic of 20 partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, logstash-configuration

We have a kafka topic that have 20 partitions.
If we have the following logstash configuration that sets 2 consumer thread per input, how many logstash worker shall i set for `pipeline.workers`?  My understanding is that it should be 10 so that 2 * 10  = 20 to ensure each topic partition have one thread to consume from?

```
input {
  kafka {
    codec => json
    bootstrap_servers => "${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}:9092"
    topics => ["service-log"]
    group_id => "service-logstash"
    consumer_threads => 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use one. Then each thread will be subscribed 10 partitions.

You'll need to do your own benchmarking, for optimal throughput.